# Why is the button OnClick event not fired when the current controls OnExit event calls SetFocus?

Tags: delphi, events, setfocus, delphi-10.1-berlin

Put 3 edits and 1 button on a new form and attach these handlers:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Button clicked');
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1Exit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit3.SetFocus;
end;
```

When Edit1 has the focus and Button1 is clicked the Button1Click event is not fired.

Why is that and is there a workaround?

Comment: Simply set the tab order instead of doing that in code.

Comment: I have a special case where the general order should be preserved, but for one Edit a different handling is required. So setting the tab order is not enough.

Comment: Rethink your design.. if button1 is clicked when Edit1 has focus, the first thing what happens is, edit1 lose the focus, but while you set the focus new the Button never get it. You should send a message in button click to your form to set the focus new. same for edit1. Exit. Sorry typing on my Phone.